# access data ForeignKey django reverse way

Tags: django, orm

I have 2 models

```
class Book(models.Model):
  STATUS_CHOICES = (
      ('draft', 'Draft'),
      ('published', 'Publish')
    )
  name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
  status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, 
                            choices = STATUS_CHOICES, 
                            default = 'draft')

class Author (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length)
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

now i want to implement query on books table and get it Author also, I don't want to apply query on author and myquery should be like that

```
select * from book left join ON book.id = author.book_id where book.status = 'published'
```

How could i implement this in django

Comment: An `Author` can only write *one* book? It looks like the modeling should be reversed.

Comment: Regardless, Django does not allow this, since this would result in a large amount of bandwidth. You can fetch the related autors in a second query. If there is however a `ForeignKey` from `Book` to `Author` you *can* do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modeling looks *odd*. Right now it means that an `Author` publishes *exactly* one book. An `Author` thus can not publish zero, or *more* books.

Likely the modeling should be reversed: a `ForeignKey` from `Book` to `Author`, or a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) in case a `Book` can have multiple authors:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Publish')
      )
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        choices = STATUS_CHOICES, 
        default = 'draft',
        db_index=True
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'Author',
        related_name='books',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Author (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

One can select objects bounded by a one-to-one (`OneToOneField`) or many-to-one relation (`ForeignKey`) with a [**`.select_related(…)`** [Djanngo-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) clause:

```
Book.objects.filter(status='published').select_related('author')
```

then the data of the `Author` is selected as well, and Django will wrap this in `Author` objects that you can access, just like you access a `ForeignKey` lazily, with `mybook.author`.

For *one-to-many* (reversed `ForeignKey`s) and *many-to-many* (`ManyToManyField`s) this is not possible. The reason is that this could result in huge amounts of bandwidth. If a book has for example five authors, it would mean that the rows of the books are repeated five times resulting in huge responses and slow performance. One can make use of [`.prefetch_related(&hellip;)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in that case. This will then fetch all the related objects in bulk, preventing an *N+1* problem.

If the modeling remains the same, we can query on the `Author` select the related books with:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__status='published').select_related('book')
```

Comment: if this is ok then my query should same i want to implement query on author and get his book like this select * from author left join book on ...

Comment: if you have any idea please share it

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal: this is not the same query, since a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is "assymetrical". You can query from the author model (see edit). But still, the modeling looks weird. It is odd that an author can write exactly *one* book, and not multiple ones.

Comment: thanks i want this  if this work fine that greate Author.objects.filter(book__status='draft').select_related('book')

Comment: and about model it just a example

Comment: i try your query today Author.objects.filter(book__status='published').select_related('book')
when i run a loop i did not get book data

Comment: @JaskaransinghRajal: but you access the book data with `for author in authors: author.book.name` for example. The point is that Django will select the book data with the author data and wrap the book data in a book object you access with `.book`.

Comment: You can inspect the query with `print(queryset.query)` with `queryset` the `QuerySet`.